# AWS - Acceidentally created VPC in 172.168.0.0/16 CIDR block, effects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

We accidentally created a VPC in 172.168.0.0/16 CIDR block, we realize we need to change this, however, does anyone know the ill effects of such an issue?

Will every call to a local ip (as we expect) actually go via internet?

Can we get an IP conflict with somebody who has taken up these IPs?

Can our internal traffic actually go out to the internet if somebody has an IP in this block?

Edit:

Our subnets routing tables route the traffic in this range into the local network, however I am pretty sure there will still be adverse effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VPC allows you to created an isolated portion of the AWS network for your own private usage.

You can choose any range of IP address in your VPC (max size is /16) and it will not conflict with other AWS customer's.

VPC network are not exposed over the internet by default.  To expose a subnet to the internet you need the following :

- attach an Internet Gateway to your VPC
- have a route table attached to your subnet with a routing rule as this '0.0.0.0/0 IGW-ID" (id of your internet gateway)
- attach a public IP address to your service (EC2, RDS, ElasticCache...) For EC2 instances, the Public IP can be assigned automatically when the instance start (parameter at the subnet level) or at any point later (using Elastic IP Address)

Now that your VPC is created, you will not be able to modify its range of IP address. You will need to create a new VPC.

VPC are explained in detail in our documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html

[UPDATE]

I tested your use case of creating a VPC with a range of publicly routable IP addresses.  I confirm that - without surprise - you can not connect to Internet based machines that are using an IP address in your VPC range (no route to host).  This behaviour is expected as VPC is trying to route these adresse locally.

Details of the test.

Create a VPC in the 54.72.0.0/16 address range.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region us-west-2 --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=test
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-e5df7680",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "test",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "State": "available",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-73848e11",
            "CidrBlock": "54.72.0.0/16",
            "IsDefault": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Create an EC2 Instance in that VPC, with an automatically assigned public IP address

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[?VpcId == `vpc-e5df7680`]'
[
    [
        {
            "Status": "in-use",
            "MacAddress": "0a:9c:b1:82:d5:ed",
            "SourceDestCheck": true,
            "VpcId": "vpc-e5df7680",
            "Description": "Primary network interface",
            "Association": {
                "PublicIp": "54.213.235.16",
                "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-213-235-16.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                "IpOwnerId": "amazon"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-7d37d025",
            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                {
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-54-72-24-135.us-west-2.compute.internal",
                    "Association": {
                        "PublicIp": "54.213.235.16",
                        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-213-235-16.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                        "IpOwnerId": "amazon"
                    },
                    "Primary": true,
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "54.72.24.135"
                }
            ],
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-54-72-24-135.us-west-2.compute.internal",
            "Attachment": {
                "Status": "attached",
                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-aaa7e1a2",
                "AttachTime": "2015-02-11T19:05:34.000Z"
            },
            "Groups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "SSH",
                    "GroupId": "sg-f2752e97"
                }
            ],
            "SubnetId": "subnet-7978bc20",
            "OwnerId": "577031028568",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "54.72.24.135"
        }
    ],
    []
]
```

Connect to that instance

```
$ ssh ec2-user@54.213.235.16
Warning: Permanently added '54.213.235.16' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/
```

Check private IP address (invalid range !)

```
[ec2-user@ip-54-72-24-135 ~]$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:9C:B1:82:D5:ED
          inet addr:54.72.24.135  Bcast:54.72.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::89c:b1ff:fe82:d5ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:23418 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2930 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:33618848 (32.0 MiB)  TX bytes:274735 (268.2 KiB)
```

Test Internet connectivity

```
[ec2-user@ip-54-72-24-135 ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=7.75 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=7.81 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=7.79 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2489ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.756/7.790/7.815/0.024 ms

[ec2-user@ip-54-72-24-135 ~]$ curl -I www.stormacq.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 19:23:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Amazon) PHP/5.5.20
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.20
Cache-Control: max-age=3, must-revalidate
WP-Super-Cache: Served supercache file from PHP
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 4f4f94bdda0837b3f79484c70f2d1348.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: us5_V9oNZak_8WAqsbBu6q9wNm4A0S6VRXGu10nDoQnWS5PYnVMwgg==
```

Works !

Now, test connectivity to an internet machine using an ip address in the same rage as our VPC

```
[ec2-user@ip-54-72-24-135 ~]$ ssh 54.72.24.171
ssh: connect to host 54.72.24.171 port 22: No route to host

[ec2-user@ip-54-72-24-135 ~]$ sudo traceroute 54.72.24.171
traceroute to 54.72.24.171 (54.72.24.171), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ec2-54-72-24-135.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (54.72.24.135)  2997.785 ms !H  2997.769 ms !H  2997.765 ms !H
```

failed.

Comment: Thats fine, I understand that and thank you for the answer, but this does not answer the question, My VPC is working, my point is that if there is an external "public ip" of 172.168 series it will conflict right? meaning which if i try to connect with a public ip of that range it would be a problem, right? Would there be any more such problems?

Comment: Best practice is to use a non routable  ip address range as specified by RFC 1918 (10.0.0.0, 172.16.0.0 or 192.168.0.0). VPC does not support direct Internet access from publicly routable ip addresses ranges. if your VPC uses a publicly routable IP address range, you must set up Internet access through a virtual private gateway, a VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect.

Comment: Awesome description and explanation!